# Spring Cloud Stream Rabbit Delivery acknowledgment

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-stream

How can one ensure in Spring Cloud Stream Rabbit guaranteed delivery. My code below : -

```
class Source {
    MessageChannel output;
    Repository repo;

    @Transactional
    void publisher(Command command){
      repo.save(command);
      output.send(MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(new Event()).build());
    }
}

class Sink {

  @StreamListener(Event.class)
  void eventListener(Event event){
     // method body
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Rabbit consumer property `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<channelName>.consumer.acknowledgeMode` on how do you want to acknowledge. The `acknowledgeMode` comes from Spring AMQP and you can refer more documentation on this [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html#amqp-inbound-ack)

Comment: thanks and if the message fails does the producer retries and how often ?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by the producer retry as I was referring to the acknowledgeMode at the consumer side. If you mean the retry at the consumer side, you can refer this documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_retry_with_the_rabbitmq_binder